# ASP.NET MVC posting list from view to controller

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have a view model in my ASP.NET MVC application:

```
public class FiltersViewModel
{
    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> AvailableFilters { get; set; } // fills a drop down menu

    public IList<TechnologyFilter> TechnologyFilters { get; set; }
    public IList<ContractTypeFilter> ContractTypeFilters { get; set; }

    public FiltersViewModel()
    {
        this.TechnologyFilters = new List<TechnologyFilter>();
        this.ContractTypeFilters = new List<ContractTypeFilter>();
    }
}
```

Then in my controller I pick up the selected value from the dropdown menu and create a specific filter object (Technology or ContractType filter) and then return the View, where I have the following code:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "Home", FormMethod.Post))
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.SelectedFilterId, Model.AvailableFilters)

    if (Model.TechnologyFilters != null)
    {
        @for (int i = 0; i < Model.TechnologyFilters.Count; i++)
        {
            <div id="technologyFilter">
            @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.TechnologyFilters[i].Name)
            @Html.DisplayFor(m => mTechnologyFilters[i].Name)
            </div>
        }
    }  
}
```

If the HTML markup is done in this way and the viewmodel is posted back from the server, the viewmodel fills the TechnologyFilters list correctly. But when I extract the for loop in a partial view, the data stops being posted back correctly and my TechnologyFilters list is empty:

The same view, but this time calling partial view:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "Home", FormMethod.Post))
{
     @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

     @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.SelectedFilterId, Model.AvailableFilters)

     if (Model.TechnologyFilters != null)
     {
         Html.RenderPartial("_TechnologyFilters", Model.TechnologyFilters);
     }
```

_TechnologyFilters.cshtml partial view:

```
@model List<MVCFilters.Models.TechnologyFilter>

<div id="technologyFilters">
    @for (int i = 0; i < Model.Count; i++)
    {
        <div id="technologyFilter">
           @Html.HiddenFor(m => m[i].Name)
           @Html.DisplayFor(m => m[i].Name)
        </div>
    }
</div>
```

The HTML data in both cases is differently generated and I would like to have a way to have it constant (to be like the first picture).

Without using Partial View:
[image]

Using Partial View:
[image]

Thanks for any help provided!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's probably a good candidate for an `EditorTemplate` to be honest, that way you don't have any issues with prefixing:

```
@Html.EditorFor(m => m.TechnologyFilters)
```

Without using an editor template though, a technique you can use is to specify the prefix in your partial declaration within the `ViewDataDictionary`, by doing:

```
Html.RenderPartial("_TechnologyFilters", Model.TechnologyFilters, new ViewDataDictionary
{
   TemplateInfo = new System.Web.Mvc.TemplateInfo { HtmlFieldPrefix = "TechnologyFilters" }
}))
```

Comment: Hi, the HtmlFieldPrefix worked, but the EditorFor did not.

Comment: @GeorgeFindulov, Using an `EditorTemplate` for typeof `TechnologyFilter` is the correct approach. If it did not work for you, consider posting the code you tried in a new question.

Comment: I have finally got this working using EditorTemplate. Thank you for your help.

Comment: @GeorgeFindulov That's great news, glad you got it working.